# Fedora 18 & Sublime Text 2: Unable to delete file

Tags: sublimetext2, fedora

I have Fedora 18 and Sublime Text 2
I can't remove file on my project from Sublime Text 2 UI.

Console displays this when I try to delete some file:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "./sublime_plugin.py", line 337, in run_
      File "./side_bar.py", line 19, in run
      File "./send2trash/plat_other.py", line 153, in send2trash
      File "./send2trash/plat_other.py", line 121, in find_ext_volume_trash
      File "./send2trash/plat_other.py", line 115, in find_ext_volume_fallback_trash
      File "./send2trash/plat_other.py", line 60, in check_create
      File ".\os.py", line 157, in makedirs
    OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/.Trash-1000'
```

I need you help :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<del>This is a bug of send2trash Python library. It happens because your file is in a mount point different from the trash folder.</del>

If you have mounted `/` and `/home` in different partitions, send2trash library can't move the file to your trash folder (usually in `/home/<user>/.local/share/Trash/`). So the delete procedure tries to locate the hard link that contains your file; in this case, it's `/`. In this directory, it looks for `Trash-<user id>` folder.

The default behaviour of your Linux file manager is prompt for permanent delete, what not happens in Sublime Text. To workaround this, type in terminal

```
sudo mkdir /.Trash-<userid>
sudo chown <user> /.Trash-<userid>
```

Now you're able to delete files and recover then from this folder.

Comment: In my case, the project I was working on was in a `/data` partition. I had to create a `/data/.Trash-1000` directory and `chown` it for it to work.